# Concatenate Multiple Returned Rows Into One Row (standard methods don't work for some reason)

Tags: postgresql, concatenation, aggregate

I have a relatively noobish question.  I say this because I feel I am just missing the obvious here.  I am simply doing what many have done and asked about previously, but typical methods I have used before are not working.  Hopefully it's just me missing something simple.

Below is part of a bigger query I am working on, but I am simply trying to combine two rows with only one column of data different, into one row with that similar column separated by a delimiter.  Easy enough with a CONCAT or STRING_AGG right?....well doesn't work for me and I don't know why.

```
SELECT  array_to_string(array_agg(ls_number), ',') "ls_number", 
            --Also tried CONCAT(ls_number, ',') and string_agg(ls_number, ',') 
            --and they don't work
        shipitem_shiphead_id, 
        shipitem_orderitem_id,
        shiphead_number

FROM    shipitem
        LEFT JOIN invhist
            ON (shipitem_invhist_id=invhist_id)
        LEFT JOIN invdetail 
            ON (invhist_id=invdetail_invhist_id)
        LEFT JOIN ls
            ON (invdetail_ls_id=ls_id)
        LEFT JOIN shiphead
            ON (shiphead_id = shipitem_shiphead_id)

WHERE   shiphead_number = '72211'

GROUP BY ls_number,
        shiphead_number, 
        shipitem_shiphead_id, 
        shipitem_orderitem_id
```

The results when the above query is ran:

[image: LINK: RESULTS WINDOW.PNG]

And you can see from the above results window that the Lot Numbers are split into 2 rows.  I need them to be on one row, with the Lot Numbers separated by the delimiter ','.  Can someone explain what I am missing here?  Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `ls_number` in your `group by` clause, meaning you'll get a different row for every distinct value of it in your result. Remove it from the `group by` clause and you should be OK.

Comment: Ha!   I had a feeling it was something obvious.  Thanks a bunch, worked like a charm.